# ajax doesn't not enter success or failure when 0 rows returned

Tags: ajax, json

I'll like to know what happens when "echo json_encode($info);" from get.php returns 0 rows as there is no value in the db. And how can i get the function to work after it. From what I have tried, if 1 or more rows returned it goes into success function. However when 0 rows is returned nothing happens. Could i get some help with this?

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getBooking.php",
                data: "id=" + $(this).find(":selected").val(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#facis").empty();
                }
                error: function() {
                    $("#facis").empty();
                }
                /*always: function() {
                    $("#facis").empty();
                }*/
```

@[Scott Selby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813523/scott-selby)
Thanks for your info, I manage to get it working after getting it to return a random value. Though I don't really have an idea why it doesn't gives error.

Comment: make getBooking.php return something when there are 0 rows , it has to return something for the client to know it worked

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, what is the actual response from the server?  It certainly should invoke *some* callback.  The `.ajax()` function doesn't really care about the *content* of the response, only the HTTP status of it.  Even an empty successful response is still successful.

Comment: @David, I'm not exactly sure to find it, but is this what u want to see? [link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img849/6548/6qjq.png)

Comment: @newprogrammer: Well, that's certainly something to look into.  If your JavaScript code is throwing an error then that would stop further code from executing.  That could cause it to *look like* the callback isn't being invoked.  It sounds like the problem is somewhere else from where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the part that could solve your problem.
In `always` that is being called in any case you can check what is the response and based on that make decisions.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBooking.php",
            data: "id=" + $(this).find(":selected").val(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#facis").empty();
            }
            error: function () {
                $("#facis").empty();
            }
            always: function (response) {
                // Check if response is empty and handle this case.
            });
```

Comment: I have tried this actually, if there are row returned, it'll end up going into always. but when there's 0 row returned, it doesn't goes into anything

Comment: @newprogrammer this is unexpected to say the least, it implies that you are not responding back to your ajax call, and function is waiting until it times out. I think problem is on PHP side.